# How to hand code people picker in sharepoint 2010 for Coded UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automate sharepoint 2010 people picker, but it is very difficult even to highlight any control inside the window.
I have used hand coding to find the window but the controls inside the window are not highlighting.

```
 WinWindow pp = new WinWindow(browserWindow);
        pp.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
        pp.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame";
        pp.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Window";
        pp.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Select People -- Webpage Dialog";
        pp.Find();
        pp.DrawHighlight();

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument doc = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument(pp);
        doc.TechnologyName = "Web";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.TagName] = "BODY";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.FrameDocument] = "False";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.RedirectingPage] = "False";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Document";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Title] = "Select People";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.PageUrl] = PAGE_URL_Here;
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = AbsolutePath_Here;
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "HtmlBody";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.FriendlyName] = "Select People";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.HasFocus] = "False";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Exists] = "True";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Enabled] = "True";
        doc.SearchProperties[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.IsTopParent] = "False";
        doc.Find();
        doc.DrawHighlight();
```

Above code easily highlights people picker window and used this object to find the control inside it is not finding any.

It is showing this error...

```
    The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'Web'
TagName:  'BODY'
FrameDocument:  'False'
RedirectingPage:  'False'
ControlType:  'Document'
```

Am i doing it right.

Comment: It seems there is a problem in recognizing controls by CodedUI. It happens when control is not fully supported by its shipper in satisfying MSAA standards. It happens with third party controls - DevExpress, Infragistics. However, I'm surprised that Sharepoint is not fully supported. I recommend you to try run tests in VS2012 if it's possible.

Comment: thanks nikita for your reply.. even i have the same thought... i will try in VS2012..

Comment: you may also try to enable logging - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496499/vs2012-write-the-testmethod-wrong-again-and-again-why#comment20212183_14496499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this,..
Well using crosshair or recording show the control on peoplepicker as separeate control but while finding through code all the control in it are shown as Edit box.
so need to store all control in a UITestControlCollection and use loop to find the control needed using its name property. 
Then do the mouse or keyboard action.

```
//write ur code here to find the parent control
UITestControlCollection controlFound = matching.FindMatchingControls();
//use loop to find the control
```